# push notification. at AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, push-notification

can anyone help me. i've stuck this coding.

it show:
"Not targeting the latest versions of Android; compatibility modes apply. Consider testing and updating this version. Consult the android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES javadoc for details."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.androidhive.pushnotifications"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<!-- GCM requires Android SDK version 2.2 (API level 8) or above. -->
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Put `android:targetSdkVersion="19"` instead of `16`. That's what the warning is complaining about - you should always try to have the latest target SDK version.

Answer (score 0):

It only means that your

```
android:targetSdkVersion
```

should be equal to 20.

Its a warning message, not an error.

Hope it helps.